# Mac OS X Yosemite default desktop blend mode?

Tags: macos, opencv, image-processing

I can not seem to find information on the blend mode that Apple uses to draw the desktop screen of OS X. To be more specific, on my desktop I have a semi-transparent window that is on top of another window. I know exactly what is drawn in the semi-transparent window and I know the alpha (=0.5) of it. You can see this from the first two images.

I have tried to "reverse" linear blend the two images using openCV which resulted in the third image which is not correct as it still shows all the drawn things if you look closely. I am sure I am using the wrong blend mode but I can not find information on what OS X uses to draw the desktop. Are there any resources on the internet that can help me understand the blend mode that OS X is using for its desktop?

[image: Input Image]
[image: Overlay Image]
[image: Incorrect Image]

EDIT:

As requested, uploaded a similar input image. I do not have the original image corresponding to the first example.

[image: Example Input Image]

Comment: Could you provide a little more info on how you're trying to perform the "reverse" linear blend?

Comment: This is from a  previous question that I asked on Stackoverflow. I have tested it out in a separate experiment. I can blend two given images and then revert it back no problem. However, doing this with the above two images does not work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28040625/removing-an-overlay-image-from-another-image

Comment: I was able to reproduce your results. I downloaded the 2 images, did the reverse and got your 3rd image with: "org = cv2.addWeighted(bld,2,fil,-1,0)"
This was on Windows, so I don't think it's a Mac thing. It might have to do with the math. Could you add the original image?

Comment: Thanks for trying to figure out what is going on, I uploaded another image as I do not have the original one.

I just tried running the project I am working on on a Windows computer and it works perfectly there. So it is either a difference between how OS X captures a screenshot or how it draws the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's OS X color management profiles were causing the problem. The first image is a screenshot of an area on the desktop which means that the colors were already adjusted to the color profile that is currently used by your display.

The second image which is used as the filter is programmatically created and is thus not adjusted to the color profile of your display. So the task is to find out what the color profile of your current display is and adjust the filter image to that profile. That way the colors will match and will allow you to correctly blend out the image.